# Summing a Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I recently came across a problem that proved particularly challenging. Unfortunately, I have not been able to complete the problem despite multiple different methods tried. It is as below:

Show that the sum of the series

$$1+3\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+7\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3+...+\left(2n-1\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}$$

is $6-R_n$ where $$R_n=\frac{2n+3}{2^{n-1}}$$

I have tried the method mentioned.

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{x^i}=\frac{1}{1-x}$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}ix^{i-1}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}ix^i=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(2i-1)x^{i-1}=\frac{x+1}{(1-x)^2}$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(2i-1)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{i-1}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}+1}{\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}$$
$$=6$$

However, the sum is finite, so this method cannot be used. I have attempted a similar approach with the finite geometric sequence sum, but got an incorrect result.

I am grateful for any help. Thanks.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: See the differentiation method below. However, I am not arriving at the required answer.

Comment: show us your working and we can see where you make the mistake?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to calculate finite sums as below:
$$
S=\sum_{k=1}^n(2k-1)x^{k-1}.
$$
Hence,
$$
S=2\sum_{k=1}^nkx^{k-1}-\sum_{k=1}^nx^k
$$
But 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^nx^k=\frac{1-x^{k+1}}{1-x}-1=\frac{x(1-x^k)}{1-x}
$$
and
$$
\sum_{k=1}^nkx^{k-1}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{k=1}^nx^k\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x(1-x^k)}{1-x}\right).
$$
Consequently,
$$
S=2\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1-x^{k+1}}{1-x}\right)-\left(\frac{x(1-x^k)}{1-x}\right).
$$
By making $x=1/2$ the desired result is obtained.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: Just one thing - I was wondering whether there exists a more elegant solution? This seems a bit bashy and fiddly, especially with the differentiation involved.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  the sum of the geometric series $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty a^i=\frac {1}{1-a}$$  If you differentiate with respect to $a$ you get $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty ia^i=\frac 1{(1-a)^2}$$
You need to deal with the fact that your series is finite.  You can set $a=\frac 12$ in the end.

Comment: I thought about this method, and arrived at the answer of 6 for the infinite sum. However, as you mentioned, the given series is finite, and therefore more difficult to compute. While differentiation works, I am somehow getting an incorrect answer.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(2i+1) \left( \frac12\right)^i&= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i\left( \frac12\right)^{i-1}+ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left( \frac12\right)^i\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left.\frac{d}{dx}x^i\right|_{x=0.5}+\frac{1-\frac1{2^n}}{\frac12} \\
&=\frac{d}{dx}\left.\left(\frac{1-x^{n}}{1-x}\right)\right|_{x=0.5}+2(1-\frac1{2^n})\\
&=\left.\frac{(1-x)(-nx^{n-1})+(1-x^{n})}{(1-x)^2}\right|_{x=0.5}+2(1-\frac1{2^n})\\
&=\frac{\frac12(-\frac{n}{2^{n-1}})+(1-\frac1{2^{n}})}{\frac14}+2-\frac1{2^{n-1}}\\
&=2(-\frac{n}{2^{n-1}})+4-\frac2{2^{n-1}}+2-\frac1{2^{n-1}}\\
&= 6-\frac{2n+3}{2^{n-1}}\end{align}

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Much appreciated.